# Nothing happening when changing select value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Ive got a select box which changes the order of the results im returning from the database depending on the select box value chosen which is linked to a switch PHP statement, problem im having is that my JavaScript doesnt seem to be working, any ideas on where im going wrong?

PHP:

```
   $batsmenQuery = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1);

   switch ($request->SortbyList){
        case 0:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
            break;
        case 1:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 2:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 3:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'DESC');
            break;
            default:
                $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');


    }

    $batsmen= $batsmenQuery->paginate(40);
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="sort">
            <select name="SortbyList" id="SortBy">
                <option value="0">A to Z</option>
                <option value="1">Z to A</option>
                <option value="2">Highest Score</option>
                <option value="3">Lowest Score</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $('#SortBy').on('change', function(e){
     $.ajax({
         url: "{{route('search.index')}}", // This is the url you make the request
         data: {SortbyList : this.value}, // Here you can send to the server the info you want in this case is only the value for the selected item
         success: function(result){

             if(result){
                 $("#SortBy").empty();  //This erase all the preview values
                 var new_options = '';
                 //This loop create the new values
                 $.each(result, function(k,v){
                     new_options += '<option value="'+ v.value +'">'+  v.name +'</option>'
                 });
                 //Now we have all the values we can put on the select
                 $("#SortBy").append(new_options);
             }

         }
 });
```

Comment: Javascript error?  Borked HTTP request?  You can check both of those in the browser devtools.

Comment: please check console for any error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '50602' in

Comment: Guessing it looks like SQL error because the word in. Check your query and try to debug if it's running properly.

Comment: No its an error with the .ajax i think, not sure the glitch or how to fix though

Comment: Check the network tab and post back the json that returns after the request

Comment: ?SortbyList=2 and it shows it all as working, as in its returning the results in preview that match the switch php statement but its not updating the page and is throwing the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '50602' in  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try wrapping the JS inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 });
```

I make a habit of going this anytime I attach any kind of attribute to an object via jquery